# Custom module category multiselect option

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I've created a module that has an option to select the categories which should have the module enabled to. For this I'm using a multiselect option and is created in my system.xml as follows:

```
<includecats>
  <label>Select categories</label>
  <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
  <source_model>admininfo/categories</source_model>
  <sort_order>30</sort_order>
  <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
  <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
  <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
  <comment>Select categories you would like to include. Use Command + Click (Mac) or Ctrl + Click (Windows).</comment>
</includecats>
```

In "Model/Categories.php" I have included:

```
<?php
class Mymodule_admininfo_Model_Categories extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

public function toOptionArray()
{
$categoriesArray = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('url_path')
    ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'asc')
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('eq'=>'1'))
    ->load()
    ->toArray();

foreach ($categoriesArray as $categoryId => $category) {
    if (isset($category['name'])) {
        $categories[] = array(
            'value' => $categoryId,
            'label' => $category['name']
        );
    }
}

return $categories;
} 
}
```

This all works like a charm. However in my module I get a list of all categories without any reference to its possible parent categories. This makes this list extremely hard to use since some categories used several times in the catalog. Without a reference to a parent or the actual id of the category it's pretty much unusable.

Current situation (example):

- Shoes
- Shoes
- Shoes

Desired situation:

- Men | Shoes
- Women | Shoes
- Childeren | Shoes

Or:

- Shoes (9)
- Shoes (10)
- Shoes (11)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had the same issue with a [hackathon module](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/layered-landing/blob/master/app/code/community/Hackathon/Layeredlanding/Model/Options/Categories.php). This is the solution we came up with. It defines the path per category separated with `/`

```
class Mymodule_admininfo_Model_Categories extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $categories = array();
        $allCategoriesCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addFieldToFilter('level', array('gt'=>'0'));
        $allCategoriesArray = $allCategoriesCollection->load()->toArray();
        $categoriesArray = $allCategoriesCollection
            ->addAttributeToSelect('level')
            ->addAttributeToSort('path', 'asc')
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('eq'=>'1'))
            ->addFieldToFilter('level', array('gt'=>'1'))
            ->load()
            ->toArray();
        foreach ($categoriesArray as $categoryId => $category)
        {
            if (!isset($category['name'])) {
                continue;
            }
            $categoryIds = explode('/', $category['path']);
            $nameParts = array();
            foreach($categoryIds as $catId) {
                if($catId == 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                $nameParts[] = $allCategoriesArray[$catId]['name'];
            }
            $categories[$categoryId] = array(
                'value' => $categoryId,
                'label' => implode(' / ', $nameParts)
            );
        }

        return $categories;
    } 
}
```

Comment: That is a very handsome solution and indeed works like a charm. Thank you Sander!